# How to authenticate the Github API request to increase rate limit?

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, oauth

I am trying to extract data from the Github API (using python requests library) and facing challenges with authenticating my API request. I have tried multiple ways including HTTPBasic Authentication, HTTPDigestAuthentication and also Oauth authentication.. Below are the codes i used-

DigestAuthentication:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    api_url = re.sub("useri", ul[i], api_url_gen)
    res = requests.get(api_url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'password'))
    json_content= json.loads(res.text)
    user_stats.append(json_content)
    print(i)
```

Basic Authentication:

```
for i in range(0,2):
    api_url = re.sub("useri", ul[i], api_url_gen)
    res = requests.get(api_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
    json_content= json.loads(res.text)
    user_stats.append(json_content)
    print(i)
```

I have also tried running this using the oauth client_id and secret_key Github, however, still when i check my rate limit in the Command prompt, it still shows 60 requests per hour and I am unable to extract data due to this.
It would be great if someone could help with this - not sure where I am going wrong with the code.
Thanks a lot.